# How to get cy.wrap data in other .js file Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

tried to put this in command.js to create a generic function that generates token when login.

```
const data = require('../fixtures/User_data.json')

Cypress.Commands.add('get_token', () => { 
    cy.api({
        method: "POST",
        url:    "https://api-stg.sample.com/login",
        body: 
        {
        "mobile_number": "+91" + data.mobile,
        "password": "p@ssw0rd"  
        }
      })
        .then((response) => {
          const token = response.body.data.access_token.token
          cy.log("Bearer token: " + token )
          cy.wrap(token).as('token')
      })
    })
```

then in my test spec file ,

```
      create_mobilenum () {
        cy.get_token()
        cy.api({
          method: "POST",
          url:    "https://api-stg.sample.com/mobile_numbers",
          headers: { 'Authorization': "Bearer " + ('@token')  },
          ...
          ...
```

but in cypress dashboard , I cannot login because it returns `token is undefined` when my spec file runs .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read [Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Avoiding-the-use-of-this), that's not how to use an alias.

They don't act like variables, you will need to extract the value

```js
cy.get('@token').then(token => {
  cy.api({
    ...
    headers: { 'Authorization': "Bearer " + token  },
```

Comment: yes, I just read the documentation. thanks for reminding this :))